# Setting default value to user extended field in Modx

Tags: php, modx

Basically I want the value of a TV (a.k.a. Template Variable) to default to the value of a user's extended field. I tried making a snippet named `get_author` with the following content:

```
$user = $modx->getUser();
if (!$user) return '';
    $profile = $user->getOne('Profile');
if (!$profile) return '';
    $extended = $profile->get('extended');
return(isset($extended['author_page'])) ? $extended['author_page'] : '';
```

And add the following code to a TV's default value property:

```
@EVAL return $modx->runSnippet('get_author');
```

It looks like the code itself works, but the value doesn't default to the desired value until the user clicks the 'set to default' button in the manager. But when I fill in a static value like `8` (so without the `@eval`) the value immediately defaults on form load. Can anyone tell me how this has to be done?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'TV'.

Comment: That's Modx slang for template variable ;)

Comment: Interesting. I'll look into this tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible, the way you trying this. The default value is calculated during rendering the template variable and not during saving the resource, only clicking on set to default will help as you mentioned above.

There are two solutions possible: Set the template variable value to the value in a plugin running on [OnDocFormSave](https://rtfm.modx.com/revolution/2.x/developing-in-modx/basic-development/plugins/system-events/ondocformsave)

```
$user = $modx->getUser());
($user) {
  $profile = $user->getOne('Profile');
  if ($profile) {
    $extended = $profile->get('extended');
    if (isset($extended['author_page'])) {
      $resource->setTVValue('my_tv', $extended['author_page']);
    }
  }
}
```

or run your code in a snippet 'AuthorPage' that uses the value of createdby or editedby as userId parameter.

```
$output = '';

$userId = $modx->getOption('userId', $scriptProperties, 0);
$user = $modx->getUser($userId);
($user) {
  $profile = $user->getOne('Profile');
  if ($profile) {
    $extended = $profile->get('extended');
    if (isset($extended['author_page'])) {
      $output = $extended['author_page'];
    }
  }
}
return $output;
```

Call that snippet like this:

```
[[AuthorPage? &userId=`[[*createdby]]`]]
```